# Querying Oracle database XML Datatype Column with Xquery and multiple nested namespaces

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xquery

I am sorry to have to come cap in hand to the community with this, I have been banging my head against this problem for a week, reading and researching the Oracle documentation and these forums. The closest model answer I could get was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755904/how-to-select-specific-values-from-xml-using-oracle-xquery)

I have this XML in an oracle colum with datatype XML:

```
    <TravelReservationRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schema.atravelcompany.com/TravelReservationTransaction" transactionType="TICKETED" creationDateTime="2015-06-30T21:01:09.0405878Z">
      <CWTTravelReservation xmlns="http://schema.atravelcompany.com/TravelReservation">
        <Reservation accountNumber="12345678" lastModifiedTimestamp="2015-06-30T21:01:09.0717888Z" recordLocatorNumber="ABCDEFG" supplierService="SUPPLIER" reservationType="Business" InternationalFlag="false" bookingDate="2015-06-30">
          <VendorList>
            <Vendor vendorCode="AD" vendorClassCode="1" vendorClassification="Air"/>
            <Vendor vendorCode="RT" vendorClassCode="3" vendorName="SOME HOTEL SOMEWHERE" vendorClassification="Hotel"/>
          </VendorList>
          <TravelerList>
            <Traveler sequence="1" guid="A:GUID">
              <Person birthDate="XXXX-XX-XX">
                <Name xmlns="http://schema.atravelcompany.com/V1" namePrefix="MR" firstName="JOHN " lastName="DOE"/>
              </Person>
              <TravelerAddress type="Alternate" line1="A HOUSE" stateProvince="A PLACE"/>
              <Client>
                <ClientTop xmlns="http://schema.atravelcompany.com/V1" guid="ANOTHER:GUID"/>
                <ClientSub xmlns="http://schema.atravelcompany.com/V1"/>
              </Client>
              <TravelerEmail emailAddress="email@address.com"/>
              <TravelerPhone usage="Mobile"/>
              <TravelerType description="SOMETHING"/>
              <EmergencyContactList>
                <EmergencyContact>
                  <EmergencyContactPhone/>
                  <EmergencyContactEmail/>
                  <UnparsedGDSContent/>
                </EmergencyContact>
              </EmergencyContactList>
              <PassportList>
                <Passport xmlns="http://schema.atravelcompany.com/V1" number="XXXXXXXX" issuingCountry="BR"/>
              </PassportList>
            </Traveler>
          </TravelerList>
          <SegmentGroupList>
            <SegmentGroup lowFareAmount="0">
              <SegmentList>
                <Segment segmentEndTimestamp="2015-07-01T07:15:00" segmentTravelDurationValue="0117" segmentTypeDescription="Air" segmentBeginTimestamp="2015-07-01T05:58:00" vendorCode="AD" vendorClassCode="1" supplierStatusCode="YK" confirmationNumber="SOMETHING" segmentNumber="1" manualBookingFlag="false">
                  <SegmentTravelerList>
                    <SegmentTraveler travelerIdRef="1"/>
                  </SegmentTravelerList>
                  <AirSegment aircraftTypeCode="E90" beginAirportCode="VCP" endAirportCode="FLN" classOfServiceCode="V" connectionType="false" eTicketFlag="true" flightNumber="4050" inFlightMealDescription="" travelDistanceValue="320">
                    <CodeShare/>
                  </AirSegment>
                </Segment>
                <Segment segmentEndTimestamp="2015-07-03T12:38:00" segmentTravelDurationValue="0120" segmentTypeDescription="Air" segmentBeginTimestamp="2015-07-03T11:18:00" vendorCode="AD" vendorClassCode="1" supplierStatusCode="YK" confirmationNumber="SOMETHING" segmentNumber="3" manualBookingFlag="false">
                  <SegmentTravelerList>
                    <SegmentTraveler travelerIdRef="1"/>
                  </SegmentTravelerList>
                  <AirSegment aircraftTypeCode="E90" beginAirportCode="A" endAirportCode="B" classOfServiceCode="G" connectionType="false" eTicketFlag="true" flightNumber="4064" inFlightMealDescription="" travelDistanceValue="320">
                    <CodeShare/>
                  </AirSegment>
                </Segment>
              </SegmentList>
              <InvoiceList>
                <Invoice ticketNumber="8003674469" travelerRefId="1" exchangeTransactionFlag="false"/>
              </InvoiceList>
            </SegmentGroup>
            <SegmentGroup>
              <SegmentList>
                <Segment segmentEndTimestamp="2015-07-03T11:18:00" segmentTypeDescription="Hotel" reservedUnitQuantity="1" segmentBeginTimestamp="2015-07-01T07:15:00" vendorCode="RT" vendorClassCode="3" supplierStatusCode="HK" confirmationNumber="000000000" currencyCode="BRL" segmentNumber="2" rateFareAmount="218.70" manualBookingFlag="false">
                  <HotelSegment cityCode="C" hotelPropertyCode="1234" propertyName="A HOTEL" roomAdultQuantity="1" roomTypeCode="C2T01J">
                    <HotelAddressList>
                      <HotelAddress type="Alternate" line1="AN ADDRESS"/>
                    </HotelAddressList>
                    <HotelEmailAddress/>
                    <HotelFaxNumber phoneNumber="1234"/>
                    <HotelPhoneNumber phoneNumber="1234"/>
                  </HotelSegment>
                </Segment>
              </SegmentList>
            </SegmentGroup>
          </SegmentGroupList>
          <ReservationPCCList>
            <ReservationPCC pseudoCityCode="CI6C" supplierService="Sabre" pseudoCityType="Booking"/>
          </ReservationPCCList>
          <BookingAgencyList>
            <BookingAgency>
              <AgencyPhoneList>
                <AgencyPhone phoneNumber="321321321321"/>
              </AgencyPhoneList>
            </BookingAgency>
          </BookingAgencyList>
        </Reservation>
      </CWTTravelReservation>
    </TravelReservationRequest>
```

I need to be able to retrieve values and possibly lists of values from this XML using something like the query in the model answer however try as I might I cannot get this working and I need some hand-holding.

My latest attempt looks like this, based on the example and just does not work at all.

```
    select t.*
            from 
            sch_edw_stg.mdf_audit a, 
            xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://schema.acompany.com/V1' as "v1"
                                        ,'http://schema.acompany.com/TravelReservation' as "resr"
                                        ,'http://schema.acompany.com/TravelReservationTransaction' as "trans"
                                        ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd"
                                        ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi")
                          ,'for $d in resr:/CWTTravelReservation:Value
                            return $d' passing a.mdf_xml_text columns value varchar2(100) path '/') as t;
```

and I have tried many other permutations and examples from here and elsewhere. The best I can do is return two null values and I am pretty sure this is down to not being able to precisely identify the node I need relative to the base of the XML.

This is the code that brings back a bunch of nulls but at least runs:

```
    SELECT xt.*
    FROM   sch_edw_stg.mdf_audit x,
           XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schema.acompany.com/TravelReservationTransaction' AS "e"),'/'
             PASSING x.mdf_xml_text
             COLUMNS 
               "VENDORCODE"    VARCHAR2(255)  PATH 'e:vendorCode',
               "VENDORCLASSCODE" VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'e:vendorClassCode',
               "VENDORCLASSIFICATION" VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'e:vendorClassification',
               "VENDORNAME" VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'e:vendorName'

             ) xt;
```

Can anyone give me a working xquery example based on this XML and give me some pointers as to *why* my attempts are failing?

Thanks.

Ed.

Comment: What kind of list do you want out initially? I mean, do you want a list of the vendors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the full path down to your Vendor nodes, including specifying the relevant namespace at each level:

```xml
/trans:TravelReservationRequest/resr:CWTTravelReservation/resr:Reservation/resr:VendorList/resr:Vendor
```

And you are accessing the attributes of those nodes so you need to use the `@` syntax to see them in your `PATH`:

```sql
select t.*
from mdf_audit a
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('http://schema.atravelcompany.com/V1' as "v1"
      ,'http://schema.atravelcompany.com/TravelReservation' as "resr"
      ,'http://schema.atravelcompany.com/TravelReservationTransaction' as "trans"
      ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd"
      ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi")
    ,'/trans:TravelReservationRequest/resr:CWTTravelReservation/resr:Reservation/resr:VendorList/resr:Vendor'
  passing a.mdf_xml_text
  columns 
    "VENDORCODE" VARCHAR2(255) PATH '@vendorCode',
    "VENDORCLASSCODE" VARCHAR2(255) PATH '@vendorClassCode',
    "VENDORCLASSIFICATION" VARCHAR2(255) PATH '@vendorClassification',
    "VENDORNAME" VARCHAR2(255) PATH '@vendorName'
) t;

VENDORCODE VENDORCLAS VENDORCLAS VENDORNAME                   
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
AD         1          Air                                      
RT         3          Hotel      SOME HOTEL SOMEWHERE
```

[SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/522358/2).

In your latest attempt the `resr:/CWTTravelReservation:Value` is just malformed. In the working-but-null you're only looking at the top-level `TravelReservationRequest`, which doesn't have child nodes called `vendorCode` etc., hence the null results. And you're looking for nodes, not attributes, with that path syntax anyway. (You also have a discrepancy between `atravelcompany.com` and `acompany.com` but I suspect you introduced that forming the question and hiding the real values).

Comment: That's fantastic thanks, I will get straight on with trying this. and yes, acompany and atravelcompany are one and the same. I looks like I have mentally implied the (example)  Reservation in resr:/Reservation. I did not think I would have to specify Reservation because I thought that would be implied in the namespace definition. Apparently not!.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that is working. I need to specify the namespace at every level down the tree, that's where I was going wrong.

Comment: @EdwardMoore - you could specify a default namespace so you don't need all the `resr:` prefixes, but it's probably safer and more self-documenting if you include them.

Comment: Alex, This is working great but I had trouble getting info from the root node. Sorted now. For completeness sake and for anyone else reading you just pass '/' as the root node to get data from line 1. not any of your namespace aliases.